# Test fails with `django.db.utils.IntegrityError`

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-tests

My test case gives me following error.

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table
>   "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint
>   "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id" DETAIL:  Key
>   (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".

In my view class I have a log entry, during the test `request.user.id` is always None. so it use `anonymous_user` which is id = 1. 
(If I commented out the  `LogEntry.objects.log_action()`, the test pass)

**My view class:**

```
class MyView(CreateAPIView):
    # For admin LogEntry
    anonymous_user_id = get_anonymous_user_id()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        ...
        """

        LogEntry.objects.log_action(
            user_id=request.user.id or self.anonymous_user_id,
            content_type_id=self.content_type_id,
            object_id=target.id,
            object_repr=str(target),
            action_flag=ADDITION,
            change_message='message',
        )

        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**My test:**

```
def test_myview_append_api_works(self):

    def myview_append(url, p1, p2):
        resp = None
        resp = self.client.post(url, data={'paraphrase': p1, 'data_id': p2})
        return resp

    url = reverse('api-my_data:paraphrase_append')
    current_qa = Qa.objects.all()[0]  # get current existing qa = the qa created in the setUp

    p1 = 'test paraphrase'
    p2 = target.id
    resp = myview_append(url, p1, p2)
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I Tried using `request_factory` to set user in request but it didn't work

```
        request = self.request_factory.post(url,  data={'paraphrase': p1, 'qa_id': p2})
        request.user = self.user

        resp = MyView.as_view()(request)
```

Can any one help me with this test.

Comment: how is the setup of your test, do you create the test user there and then save it in `self`? tests use a brand new database and you have to create anything that is required and is not in the migrations in the setup method.

Comment: @DanieleBernardini yes I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LogEntry.user` requires an actual user record in your database. As a part of your setUp code in your test you need to create a user whose id will map to the id that's returned by get_anonymous_user_id.

Side note, you're heading down a path of pain with

```
class MyView(CreateAPIView):
    # For admin LogEntry
    anonymous_user_id = get_anonymous_user_id()
```

If for some reason the data changes such that `get_anonymous_user_id` would return a different value, the server will need to restart in order to update this value as the class will be loaded into memory. The other potential problem is that if `get_anonymous_user_id` hits the database, it means as your class is being loaded into memory, it's running hitting the database. If that sql query were to perform poorly then it's going to take longer to deploy.